# Replacing foreach with threading

Tags: python, multithreading

My program basically has to get around 6000 items from the DB and calls an external API for each item. This almost takes 30 min to complete. I just thought of using threads here where i could create multi threads and split the process and reduce the time. So i came up with some thing like this. But I have two questions here. How do i store the response from the API that is processed by the function.

```
api = externalAPI()
for x in instruments:
    response = api.getProcessedItems(x.symbol, days, return_perc);
    if(response > float(return_perc)):
         return_response.append([x.trading_symbol, x.name, response])
```

So in the above example the for loop runs for 6000 times(`len(instruments) == 6000`)

Now lets take i have splited the 6000 items to 2 * 3000 items and do something like this

```
class externalApi:

 def handleThread(self, symbol, days, perc):
    //I call the external API and process the items 
    // how do i store the processed data

 def getProcessedItems(self,symbol, days, perc):
    _thread.start_new_thread(self.handleThread, (symbol, days, perc))
    _thread.start_new_thread(self.handleThread, (symbol, days, perc))
    return self.thread_response
```

I am just starting out with thread. would be helpful if i know this is the right thing to do to reduce the time here.

P.S : Time is important here. I want to reduce it to 1 min from 30 min.

Comment: You have a throughput of about 1/3 of a second per call, it seems excessive. Perhaps if you get proper performance you won't need to mutltithread?

Comment: But I want to minimize the time without a upgrade. is multithreading a right way to do it? if yes how do i go about this /

Comment: Assuming this is CPU-bound if your current processing takes time T on a single core, you will need 30 cores to make the this run in T/30 (or thereabouts, there will be some overhead to do the multithreading). There is no benefit and more overhead from trying to create more threads than you have CPU cores. And will the external API process 30x the rate of calls all in parallel? No such thing as a free lunch :-(

Comment: @barny: My gut feeling is that this isn't CPU bound. It of course depends on _how_ external the API is, but to me it sounds like something communicating externally, making the whole thing IO bound. Also, if it really is CPU bound, it is imperative that the GIL is released, or there won't be any speedup at all, no matter the number of cores.

Comment: By "proper performance" I didn't mean new hardware, I meant fixing your code so that the single-thread version works properly. If your API service is really slow, hitting it multiple times won't speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [worker-queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_queue) pattern like so...

you will have a queue of jobs, each worker will take a job and work on it, the result it will put at another queue, when all workers are done, the result queue will be read and process the results

```
def worker(pool, result_q):
  while True:
    job = pool.get()
    result = handle(job) #handle job
    result_q.put(result)
    pool.task_done()



q = Queue.Queue()
res_q = Queue.Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
  t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q, res_q))
  t.setDaemon(True)
  t.start()

for job in jobs:
  q.put(job)

q.join()       

while not res_q.empty():
   result = res_q.get()
   # do smth with result
```

Answer (score 0):

The worker-queue pattern suggested in [shahaf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690745/7738328) works fine, but Python provides even higher level abstractions, in `concurret.futures`. Namely a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which will take care of the queueing and starting of threads for you:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30)
responses = executor.map(process_item, (x.symbol for x in instruments))
```

The main complication with using the `excutor.map()` is that it can only map over one argument, meaning that there can be only one input to `proces_item` namely `symbol`).

However, if more arguments are needed, it is possible to define a new function, which will fixate all arguments but one. This can either be done manually or using the special Python `partial` call, found in `functools`:

```
from functools import partial
process_item = partial(api.handleThread, days=days, perc=return_perc)
```

Applying the `ThreadPoolExecutor` strategy to your current probelm would then have a solution similar to:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial

class Instrument:
    def __init__(self, symbol, name):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.name = name

instruments = [Instrument('SMB', 'Name'), Instrument('FNK', 'Funky')]

class externalApi:
    def handleThread(self, symbol, days, perc):
        # Call the external API and process the items 
        # Example, to give something back:
        if symbol == 'FNK':
            return days*3
        else:
            return days

def process_item_generator(api, days, perc):
    return partial(api.handleThread, days=days, perc=perc)

days = 5
return_perc = 10
api = externalApi()

process_item = process_item_generator(api, days, return_perc)

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30)
responses = executor.map(process_item, (x.symbol for x in instruments))

return_response = ([x.symbol, x.name, response]
                   for x, response in zip(instruments, responses)
                   if response > float(return_perc))
```

Here I have assumed that `x.symbol` is the same as `x.trading_symbol` and I have made a dummy implementation of your API call, to get some type of return value, but it should give a good idea of how to do this. Due to this, the code is a bit longer, but then again, it becomes a runnable example.